# When object is a argument of function, why does function use copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm studying about copy constructors now. I learned that copy constructor is called when we make a object with already made object. And I heard that When we use object as a argument in function, copy constructor is called.

I want to know what happens inside function. How can function knows that function have to use copy constructor?
I think inside function, the passed argument is assigned to function parameter so that copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think inside function, the passed argument is assigned to function parameter

No. The arguments are essentially local variables of the called function, *except they are created by the caller before* the execution goes into the function. The function does not even know how they were constructed.

> why does function use copy constructor?

So this assumption is wrong, the function does not use copy constructor on its arguments. *The caller does* (if argument is a variable and passed by value, so copy needs to be made).

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask one more question?
Then you mean When I call a function using object as an argument like hello(a) in main func,
That object 'a' is passed to function 'hello' 's local variable by copy constructor used by main func?

Comment: @KK Arguments are created before the call (and destructed after the call if needed) by the caller. They are put to stack or registers by caller. The function just trusts they are there, as defined by the function prototype. They are _like_ local variables, accessed the same way from the machine code, except for this difference in what creates them. So from the function's "point of view", the arguments just... are there. The caller does what it needs, including using copy constructor if that's what needed.

Comment: @KK If you need to get deeper than that, you need to look up "calling convention". That is the specification (compiler/platform/CPU/operating system specific, not part of C++ standard) of how exactly function arguments are passed at CPU machine code level.

Comment: @KK The function does not look up "where is the argument x", because at machine code level, its location is defined by the function prototype, and the function just accesses it without any lookup or checks. And the caller knows to put it in the correct place by looking at the function prototype; that is, the compiler generates the machine code which just directly puts  the argument in the right place, which it knows from the prototype.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a big help to me

Answer (score 3):

> How can function knows that function have to use copy constructor?

When passing the argument by value, the **parameter** is **initialized** by the passed argument. And from [copy constructor's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

> The copy constructor is called whenever an object is **initialized** (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from another object of the same type (unless overload resolution selects a better match or the call is elided), which includes :

> - **function argument passing**: `f(a);`, where `a` is of type `T` and `f` is `void f(T t);`

So, since the passed argument is used to initialize the parameter(in case of pass by value), according to the above quoted statement, the copy constructor will be used.

---

Do note that in C++, **assignment** and **initialization** are different.

---

Additionally, note that **move constructor** can also be used instead of copy constructor in case the argument is an `rvalue`. From [move constructor's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> The move constructor is typically called when an object is **initialized** (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from rvalue (xvalue or prvalue) (until C++17)xvalue (since C++17) of the same type, including

> - **function argument passing**: `f(std::move(a));`, where `a` is of type `T` and `f` is `void f(T t);`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's inaccurate to say that a copy constructor is called.

Let me give some examples:

```
void foo(string b);
...
{
    string a = "asdf";
    foo(a); // copy constructor is called to make string b
    foo(std::move(a)); // move constructor is called to make string b
    foo("asdfg"); // the string b is constructed inplace from "asdfg"
}
```

Basically, `foo` has the `string` as a local parameter and it needs to be constructed in some way. How exactly it is constructed is defined by the call.

Comment: An [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c71849619a6eee05) to illustrate.